# Url Download to Server 500 Error after long time

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I'm using fopen and fwrite to download url files (zip,rar etc) direct to my server, but if the file is large or takes long time to download returns 500 Error.

PHP

```
$destination_folder = 'files/';

$url = $_POST['url'];
$newfname = $destination_folder . basename($url);

$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if ($file) {
  $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

  if ($newf)
  while(!feof($file)) {
    fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
  }
}

if ($file) {
  fclose($file);
}

if ($newf) {
  fclose($newf);
}
```

Comment: Use `ini_set('max_execution_time',0);` let me know if that works.

Comment: Do you mean your script is timing out? If so, either set the max script execution time to something longer in your PHP settings or consider it a limitation of this method of copying files. You could split the file up or offload it to another process, or you could add it to a message queue somewhere, but those are all a lot more complex than what you're looking at.

Comment: No I have set execution time I think is script runtime something going wrong when runs long time

Comment: I suggest using something actually designed for fetching files, like wget 
You are likely exceeding PHP max runtime, or using more memory than is allowed.

Comment: Maybe yes reaching maximum memory allowed so use wget with exec?